# SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am getting this error for the SQL script shown below:

> SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL  ANSI_WARNINGS  ANSI_PADDING'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or in 393

Also, it worked on one SQL Server, but on another I get the error. Both are SQL Server 2016.

I also observed that the error is if I use driver 'ODBC driver 13 for sql server' to connect to DB.
But if I use 'SQl server native client' then there is no issue.

```
/****** Object:  Stored Procedure dbo.TAHolidayCal_FindBrkCls     ******/
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('dbo.TAHolidayCal_FindBrkCls'))
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TAHolidayCal_FindBrkCls
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TAHolidayCal_FindBrkCls
    (@calDate DATETIME,
     @holCalID CHAR(4),
     @InstID01 CHAR(13),
     @InstID02 CHAR(13) = NULL,
     @InstID03 CHAR(13) = NULL,
     @InstID04 CHAR(13) = NULL,
     ..... and so on and so forth up to ...
     @InstID99 CHAR(13) = NULL,
     @InstID100 CHAR(13) = NULL
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        i.InstrumentID, i.Status, i.Product, i.SysDescription, 
        e.TradeAdminStatus, CONVERT(DATE, @calDate) AS PayDate
    FROM 
        Instrument i 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        EXTTradeStatus e ON (i.InstrumentID = e.InstrumentID) 
                         AND (i.VersionNumber = e.VersionNumber)
    INNER JOIN 
        EXTBreakClause b ON (i.InstrumentID = b.InstrumentID)
                         AND (i.VersionNumber = b.VersionNumber)
    WHERE 
       (i.VersionNumber = 0)
       AND i.InstrumentID IN (@InstID01, @InstID02, @InstID03, 
                               ......
                              @InstID97, @InstID98, @InstID99, @InstID100)
       AND (@holCalID IN (SELECT value
                          FROM
                              (SELECT 
                                   CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), b.BreakClauseDefn))) AS BCD(X)   
                          CROSS APPLY 
                              BCD.X.nodes('//Definitions/BreakDefn/NotificationHolidayCalendar/text()') NHC(X)
                          CROSS APPLY 
                              string_split(NHC.X.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), ',')
                        )
                        OR
                        @holCalID IN (SELECT value
                                      FROM
                                          (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), b.BreakClauseDefn))) AS BCD(X)   
                                      CROSS APPLY BCD.X.nodes('//Definitions/BreakDefn/ExerciseHolidayCalendar/text()') EHC(X)
                                      CROSS APPLY string_split(EHC.X.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), ',')
    )
)
AND
(
    CONVERT(DATE, @calDate) in
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(DATE, ND.X.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))
        FROM  
        (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),b.BreakClauseSchedule))) AS BCS(X)   
        CROSS APPLY BCS.X.nodes('//Schedule/Event/NotificationDate/text()') ND(X)   
    )
    OR
    CONVERT(DATE, @calDate) in
    (
        SELECT CONVERT(DATE, ED.X.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))
        FROM  
        (SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(varbinary(MAX),b.BreakClauseSchedule))) AS BCS(X)   
        CROSS APPLY BCS.X.nodes('//Schedule/Event/ExerciseDate/text()') ED(X)   
    )
) 

SET NOCOUNT OFF

END
GO

EXECUTE Create_Permissions 'dbo.TAHolidayCal_FindBrkCls'
GO
```

Comment: The first step would be to check what SET options are required for indexed views.  If it works on one server but not on another, that would suggest the SET options are different between the servers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: And the second step would be to **learn about table-valued parameter types** to avoid having to pass 100+ individual parameters!!

Comment: Hi Joe, I check the SET options (is_ansi_null_default_on, is_ansi_nulls_on, is_ansi_padding_on, is_ansi_warnings_on, is_arithabort_on, is_concat_null_yields_null_on, is_numeric_roundabort_on, is_quoted_identifier_on) . All are same in both the servers

Comment: Some set options have to be applied correctly at the time you invoke `CREATE PROCEDURE...` as they get stored in the procedure's options. In other words apply `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS ON;` before `CREATE PROCEDURE`. At run time the other options should be applied correctly before executing the stored procedure: `SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF; SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT ON;`

Comment: Okay, here's something weird. I just created a new DSN using the same driver and the issue got resolved. I still don't know the reason but it's not working with the old DSN even though both are exactly the same.